# Android FrameLayout place 4x4 image with title

Tags: android

I need in FrameLayout place 4x4 images with title (title must wrap as long).

I use next code an have result

[image]

```xml
<FrameLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            >
            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Photo 1"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Photo 2"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>
           2 TEXTVIEW
        <TableRow
        </TableRow>
           2 IMAGEVIEW
        <TableRow
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

, but on same phones after set image FrameLayout resised.
[image: Resised]

Answer (score 1):

You must adjust parameter for ImageView: `scaleType(int)`

[ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

After that, you can set enable `adjustViewBounds` for ImageViews in your xml.

Comment: Thank. Now images show as 4x4. But not fill all place. http://clip2net.com/s/3nU87fd

Comment: Which scale type you use and have you enabled adjustViewBounds?

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter"                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: Try to use centerInside instead fitCenter